# Tiff Viewer for Chrome

Tags: chrome, image-viewer

I do a lot of work with [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) files. They're great for archiving images but they can be a pain to work with. Most image formats open directly in a browser window but TIFF files do not. Usually I have to download and open them using the Windows Image Viewer. That's easy enough but when I'm clicking through hundreds of images it would be nice to have them open in the browser. Can someone please recommend a Chrome plugin that will allow me to view TIFF images in the browser window?

Chrome Version: 33.0.1750.154
Operating System: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Price: Free is preferred but will pay up to 5 USD.

Required Features: TIFF viewing
Optional Features: Zoom, support for TIFF extensions or other lossless image formats

Note: I'm aware that Safari and IE 9 and higher support TIFF files but the only two browsers I'm allowed to have at work are IE and Chrome and one of my projects only works in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used it myself, but it looks like [AlternaTiff](http://www.alternatiff.com/) could be your best bet. It is a free plugin that works for chrome.

An [article on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/331534/tiff-viewer-plugin-for-chrome) had to hack it to get it to work for chrome, but this was four years ago. I'm sure it is easier to install now.

Answer (score 1):

[Docs PDF/Powerpoint Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en) should fill you needs. Despite it's atrociously poor naming 
it supports a *lot* more formats **including tiff**; here's the configuration screen:
[[image]]

It works pretty well and I've never run into any significant issues with it - though I'm mainly a firefox guy so I haven't used it all that much.

Answer (score 0):

ITV - Inline Tiff Viewer 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inline-tiff-viewer/kkfncbfgbghoklckdmeljdjohpkknlma

It is available for free in the Chrome Store.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to say *why* this will help the OP. And edit your link, it seems to have a personal ID attached.